# pypiwin32 alternatives for Mac

Tags: macos, importerror, chatbot

Is there an alternative for pypiwin32 on Mac?

I'm doing a tutorial on how to create a chatbot, however I keep getting an import error. I was given advice to install pypiwin32 but soon realized it only works for windows and not on osx. Below is the code for the chatbot where I get the import error on.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print("Requested driver is not found")
except RuntimeError:
print("Driver failed to initialize")

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an alternative to pypiwin32 for OSX, maybe you can share what your error is so we can help you that way?

Not an answer but I can't comment yet...

Comment: I keep getting 'Requested driver is not found' when I run the code.

Comment: does something like this solve you problem? https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/1 .

Comment: I also found that you could try this: pip install -U pyobjc. Maybe you can not catch the exception and look what it gives as error when executing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it on mac OSX, you need to additionally install:

pip install pyobjc

it will work. I had tried the following:

import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('nsss')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

after installing pyobj and it is working now :)